# Invalid conversion from runtime type Boolean to List<>

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

**Error**

> common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Boolean to `List<BusinessCardRequestControllerExtension.BCRWrapper>`

By removing the value from each checkbox would make the table disappear, so what is a substitute for the checkbox value that I have currently?

**Visualforce Page**

```
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Step 2: Choose your preferred style and order quantity." collapsible="false" columns="1" id="styleAndQuantitySection">
                <script>
                colorPageBlock(document.getElementById("{!$Component.styleAndQuantitySection}"), "#4d6f85");
                </script>
                <apex:outputText value="Please make your selection of style and quantity.
                                        (You may only make ONE selection per request)" style="font-variant:small-caps"></apex:outputText>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrpObj}" var="c" id="priceTable" rendered="{!Info_In_Wrp.Size!=0}" onRowDblClick="updateRowColor(this)">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Order Quantity" value="{!c.bcrObj.Order_Quantity__c}" id="orderquantity">
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Thermal">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrpObj}" id="thermal" onchange="enableDisable(this);"/>
                        <apex:outputLabel for="thermal" value="{!c.bcrObj.Thermal__c}">
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Engraved">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrpObj}" id="engraved" onchange="enableDisable(this);"/>
                        <apex:outputLabel for="engraved" value="{!c.bcrObj.Engraved__c}">
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Engraved Reorder (no changes)">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrpObj}" id="engravedreorder" onchange="enableDisable(this);"/>
                        <apex:outputLabel for="engravedreorder" value="{!c.bcrObj.Engraved_Reorder__c}">
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Braille">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrpObj}" id="braille" onchange="enableDisable(this);"/>
                        <apex:outputLabel for="braille" value="{!c.bcrObj.Braille__c}">
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Braille Reorder (no changes)">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrpObj}" id="braillereorder" onchange="enableDisable(this);"/>
                        <apex:outputLabel for="braillereorder" value="{!c.bcrObj.Braille_Reorder__c}">
                        </apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>   
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Where am I converting a `Boolean` to a `List` and how can I fix it?

Comment: You still have the same problem five separate times: `<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrpObj}" ...>`. And please stop insisting you have proper syntax. The compiler is not wrong.

Comment: @AdrianLarson And please do not down vote. I am trying my hardest to figure this out. I am not trolling or trying to be funny

Comment: Perhaps not, but you are being rather insistent you're doing nothing wrong when that's clearly not the case. It doesn't make much sense why those `<inputCheckbox>` tags would have *anything* to do with rendering. Perhaps you should ask a separate question in that regard.

Comment: Consider a reductive approach. A common concept in error reproduction is Minimum Viable Reproduction (MVR). Often times in creating your MVR, you will realize what you are doing wrong and solve your own problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this area here:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapList}" onchange="enableDisable(this);"/>
```

*(There's a few instances of this problem, so only one is illustrated here.)*

You're trying to bind the entire wrapList to a Boolean value. You probably meant to do something like this:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="thermal" value="{!c.bcrObj.Thermal__c}" 
       onchange="enableDisable(this);"/>
```

Your outputText was probably meant to be an apex:outputLabel, like this:

```
<apex:outputLabel for="thermal" 
       value="{!$ObjectType.Business_Card_Request_Price__c.fields.Thermal__c.Label}" />
```